# Is it wise to remove redundant self-signatures from my PGP key?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, pgp, gnupg, self-signed

I have changed expiration date of my pgp key several times. Recently I looked at it and started to worry about the mess I can see there:

```
$ gpg --list-sigs AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
pub   4096R/AAAAAAAA 2014-11-23
uid                  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2018-03-01  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2016-04-11  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2016-11-11  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
uid                  Foo Bar (org) <foo@bar.org>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2017-10-12  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2018-03-01  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2016-04-11  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2016-11-11  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2014-11-23  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
uid                  Foo Bar (net) <foo@bar.net>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2018-03-01  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
sub   4096R/BBBBBBBB 2014-11-23 [expires: 2019-01-11]
sig          AAAAAAAA 2017-10-12  Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
```

From [What do these signatures of my PGP key mean?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170528/what-do-these-signatures-of-my-pgp-key-mean) I know that the redundant signatures come from key manipulation.

I would like to remove them so my public key is small. I think I can use `clean` option of `gpg --edit AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` for that purpose.

However I wonder whether there are is any reason for which I should not remove the redundant self-signatures?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, when importing the public key, duplicate signatures are automatically removed. Because of this, anyone who imports your public key will *already* have a copy without the redundant signatures. Removing them yourself just makes it so that they do not need to do it themselves.

Comment: I had successfully removed the redundant signatures. However as I have fetched the key (with `gpg --fetch AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`) they has reappeared.

Comment: They may still exist in the keyserver, in which case the question becomes how to update the keyserver public key to remove these signatures.

Comment: Weren't they supposed to be removed on import? Or is it a client - dependent behaviour?

Comment: @abukaj Yes they should be removed on import, at least for GnuPG.

Comment: It seems it is not the case at least for GnuPG 1.4.16.